# How do I share secret key files with Docker containers following 12 Factor App?

Tags: appsec, docker

I am building an API and trying to follow the 12 Factor App methodology. Using Docker, the methodology says containers must be disposable.

Assuming the API will have high traffic, multiple docker containers will be running with the same app, connecting to the same database.

Certain fields in the database are encrypted and stored with a reference to the file containing the passphrase. - This is done so the passphrase can be updated, and old data can still be decrypted.

With a Docker container and **following 12 Factor App**, how should I provide the key files to each of the containers?

Am I correct in assuming I would need a separate server to handle the creating of new key files and distributing them over the network?

Is there secure software, protocols or services that do this already, or would I need a custom solution?

**Update**

I have read that Vault by HashiCorp or Kubernetes can handle secret sharing between containers however, I am not sure if that will work for me, as I need an automated task to create a new passphrase file, and then distribute it to the containers.

Answer (score 1):

12 factor says that the config needs to be stored in the environment. So why not simply pass the secrets to the container over environment variables? If there are many, pass a master key to a key store that is lying on a volume mounted at start.

Comment: It's a resource rather than a config item. There could be a number of these files, so this would end up with an admin having to download the latest ones before running the containers. If a new file is created, it would require the containers to be restarted with the new values.

Comment: Than how about holding encrypted secrets in a database table? Masterkey goes over environment variables. No refresh or restart is necessary.